# Does SE have a site for psychology questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm not sure if it exists or not, but does Stack Exchange have a site for asking psychology questions? And if not, is it possible to create one?

Answer (score 6):

[Cognitive Sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) may offer what you wish.

Their site description reads:

> Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for practitioners, researchers, and students in cognitive science, psychology, neuroscience, and psychiatry.

As with many sites, they are not able to offer diagnoses, so questions should rather be *about* the subjects that they cover on their [help page](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and, if in doubt, you can always ask on their meta or review their questions asked to see if you can find one similar to what you're looking for.

As a note, if you use the site switcher in the top bar, you can often find sites by topic, even if that's not the site's name. I couldn't remember "Cognitive Sciences" but found the site by typing in "psychology" and it matched the site description.

If you'd like to *propose* a site, that should be done on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), not Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Cogsci was created explicitly to unite similar related fields/interests that were struggling to reach critical mass on their own. So I can verify: yes psychology questions are on topic here; and no, they are not able to offer individual diagnoses,